# Test multiple regex on each document

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am getting all documents from a mongodb collection (millions), and I have a lot of regex in a postgreSQL.
I wanted to test each regex until one match on multiple fields containded in documents.

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

I tried with a `Filter Row` step, but I can't figure how to loop over all regex from postgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem by using a *Join rows (Cartesian Product)* component. One of your inputs will have to read in the docs, the other will have to read in the regular expressions. The join component will create a outer product from these resulting in every possible combination of regex expressions and docs. This stream you will have to feed into the *Filter Rows* component and send the result to some output.

The following transformation will mimick this approach (it reads from CSV files but that should not make any difference to reading it from postgreSQL or MungoDB):

[image: transformation]

The input data for "documents" is configured as follows:

[image: csv input for docs]

The input data for "regular expressions" is configured as follows:

[image: csv input for regular expressions]

The *Join Rows* does not have to be configured at all since we will *NOT* provide a join condition and hence making it effectively an full outer join.

In the *Filter* component you will have to use the `DOC_TEXT` and the `REGEX_TEXT` fields to execute the check base upon `REGEXP` operator.

[image]

For this document input

```
DOC_ID;DOC_TEXT
1;DFGBGGG
2;UHLLJAL
3;JJJJHHH
4;FGAKKBL
```

and this regex input

```
REGEX_ID;REGEX_TEXT
1;.*A.*
2;.*B.*
```

the transformation will output the following result:

```
DOC_ID;DOC_TEXT;REGEX_ID;REGEX_TEXT
1;DFGBGGG;2;.*B.*
2;UHLLJAL;1;.*A.*
4;FGAKKBL;1;.*A.*
4;FGAKKBL;2;.*B.*
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted in the first place, but it's working fine, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! I guess there's room for improvement. What exactly does not fit your needs?

Comment: The problem for me is that if a a document is matching with multiple regex, I will have duplicate of them. I don't need it right now, but I know that i can do it with a post step.

Comment: How about inserting an aggregation component? I cannot do this right now because I don't have access to my development environment. But tonight I could update my answer.

Comment: You can if you want, but don't bother yourself just for that, the current result is fine for me.

Comment: Nice, I was looking for a solution like that! With the "Write to log" step I can log every row that has an unexpected content now.